# Device Issue: No USB keyboard after Ubuntu 15.10 update

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard, intel-nuc, 15.10

After my last update, my Ubuntu box has become very unstable, and my USB keyboard now longer works.

It's not my bios, as the keyboard works during startup -- the problem starts at user login, apparently once the system drivers load.

I noticed that in my driver settings, I have an intel device (micro controller?) that indicates "not working", but previously it was fine.  It apparently got updated and may be part of the problem.

I'd have tried a few things at this point but.... I DONT HAVE A WORKING KEYBOARD!  The machine only has USB ports, so I don't have an immediate solution for a KB during a normal desktop boot.

- Does anyone know of any way of addressing a problem like this?  I've tried safe mode, but the safe mode menu doesn't appear to work.
- Would booting via an install drive be helpful?  If so is there some way I can boot via the thumb drive and then modify my local install?
- I'm open to other suggestions...

So in summary, if there's some way to fix this up and save me a complete reinstall, I'm all ears.

(PS: I've got lots of unix experience, but I'm "new" to Ubuntu desktop)

Comment: Only USB ports? Get a USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Neither did my mouse. However, when I wanted to enter safe mode, and pressing the left shift key did not work, I tried to repeatedly enter the Esc key (like crazy repeat), it suddenly started working again. Both keyboard and mouse are now working.

Comment: If you read my answer, I have not given any opinion, only a solution I found that made my keayboard and mouse work again.

However, I did probarbly speak to soon. After several reboots the problem came back. But doing the same trick, I got it to work again. It is not solved, and is rather unstable, but you do get the keyboard to work and therefore have the posibility to update or modify whatever is needed. That I do not have4 a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly, you don't have to reinstall your system. I had the same issue this morning (also with 15.10) and solved it. Since Unix experience is not your problem, I will keep it short:

-**Option 1:** Use ssh to log into your computer. Install all available updates.

-**Option 2:** Boot via USB install disk, perform a chroot and install all updates.